# Docker image creation using RPM

Tags: linux, rhel, docker

I used the docker file bellow to create a docker image

[image]

So, my problem is, when I was building it, the below error appeared. please help me solving it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ADD` command needs the filename to be *relative* to the current directory.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot ADD ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

This means you can't `ADD /aa/http....` because the leading `/` is stripped and treated as if it was `ADD aa/http...`

You'll also have a second problem at the `RUN` phase; you're copying the files to the root of the container, but the `rpm` command is looking for them inside a `/aa` directory.